Refresh token in Dio with Interceptor as a singleton never catches connectionTimeout exception
This is my TokenInterceptor class
class TokenInterceptor extends QueuedInterceptorsWrapper {
  @override
  void onError(DioException err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    print("ON ERROR!! INTERCEPTOR");
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401 || err.response?.statusCode == 403) {
      // refreshing access token

   
      bool isRefreshTokenSuccessfull = await NetworkManager().refreshTheToken();
      // if successfull `fetch` and `resolve`
      if (isRefreshTokenSuccessfull) {
        // retrying request with same requestOptions
        Response response =
            await NetworkManager().retryRequest(err.requestOptions);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return handler.resolve(response);
        } else {
          logout();
          return handler.reject(err);
        }
      } else {
        logout();
        return handler.reject(err);
      }
    } else {
      return handler.next(err);
    }
  }

  void logout() {
    injector<PreferenceManager>().clearTokens();
    Navigator.of(navigationKey.currentContext!)
        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(LoginScreen.route, (route) => false);
  }

  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
    print("ON REQUEST!! INTERCEPTOR");
    String? accessToken = injector<PreferenceManager>().getAccessToken();
    if (accessToken != null && !options.extra.containsKey('dummy')) {
      options.headers.addAll({'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'});
    }
    return handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    print("ON RESPONSE!! INTERCEPTOR");
    return handler.next(response);
  }
}

ApiInstance class
class NetworkManager {
  ///
  static NetworkManager instance = NetworkManager._();

  /// dio instance
  Dio dio = Dio();

  String registerPath = 'account/api/register';
  String products = 'account/api/news';
  String login = 'api/token/';
  String refreshTokenPath = 'api/token/refresh/';

  /// private constructor
  NetworkManager._() {
    BaseOptions options = BaseOptions();
    // python3 manage.py runserver {YOUR_WIFI_IP_ADDRESS}:8000
    options.baseUrl = 'http://192.168.*.*:8000/';
    options.connectTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);
    options.receiveTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);
    dio.options = options;
    dio.interceptors.add(TokenInterceptor());
    dio.interceptors.add(PrettyDioLogger(
        responseHeader: true,
        requestHeader: true,
        responseBody: true,
        requestBody: true,
        request: true));
  }

  ///
  factory NetworkManager() => instance;

  /// register
  Future<bool> signUp(RegisterUserDTO registerUserDTO) async {
    try {
      Response<dynamic> response =
          await dio.post(registerPath, data: registerUserDTO.toJson());
      return response.statusCode == 200;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> authenticateOrLogin(LoginDTO loginDTO) async {
    try {
      Response<dynamic> response =
          await dio.post(login, data: loginDTO.toJson());
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        PreferenceManager preferenceManager = injector<PreferenceManager>();
        String accessToken = response.data['access'] as String;
        String refreshToken = response.data['refresh'] as String;
        return await preferenceManager.saveAccessToken(accessToken) &&
            await preferenceManager.saveRefreshToken(refreshToken);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return false;
  }

  ///
  Future<ProductResponse?> getProducts() async {
    try {
      Response<dynamic> response = await dio.get(products);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return ProductResponse.fromJson(response.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }

  ///
  Future<bool> refreshTheToken() async {
    try {
      PreferenceManager preferenceManager = injector<PreferenceManager>();
      String? refreshToken = preferenceManager.getRefreshToken();
      if (refreshToken != null) {
        Response<dynamic> response = await dio.post(refreshTokenPath,
            data: {'refresh': refreshToken},
            options: Options(extra: {"dummy": true}));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          String accessToken = response.data['access'] as String;
          String refreshToken = response.data['refresh'] as String;
          return await preferenceManager.saveAccessToken(accessToken) &&
              await preferenceManager.saveRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        }
      }
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<Response> retryRequest(RequestOptions options) {
    return dio.fetch(options);
  }
}

The Problem is with the await NetworkManager().refreshTheToken() method. it just blocked
Here everything works, when I call the refreshTheToken with new Dio instance it throws the connection timeout exception but why doesn't it throw exception with the same instance?
Doctor Summary
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.4, on macOS 14.1 23B74 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for  iPhone 12 Pro. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same
      local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

